# npm error required vs actual version?

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I got a npm error installing express, what does this mean?  I think it means I have to uninstall node and reinstall it?  Or upgrade it perhaps.  Can't figure out what I'm supposed to do and I'm reluctant to start screwing with it for fear of corrupting something.

```
My-Comp:websockets101 myuser$ npm install express
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7 Error: Unsupported
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at checkEngine (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:567:14)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at nextStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/chain.js:54:8)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at chain (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/chain.js:27:3)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at installOne_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:545:3)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at installOne (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:485:3)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:422:9
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/async-map.js:57:35
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/async-map.js:57:11
npm ERR! error installing express@3.0.0beta7     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: connect@2.3.9
npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.5.0"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.0.17","node":"v0.4.11"}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/myuser/projects/websockets101
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a goof-up on the Express maintainer's part. He's letting Express 3.0.0 beta install on Node 0.4.x installs, but is requiring a library that will only install on 0.5.x and higher.

Try `npm install express@2.x` to get the latest release version (3.0 is still in beta) which is guaranteed to work on Node 0.4.x, *or* upgrade to the latest version of Node.js (now 0.8.1, I believe).

Comment: How do you upgrade your version of node?

Comment: That depends quite drastically on what operating system you're using. Node.js runs on Linux, Mac, Windows, Solaris, and BSD, that I'm aware of.

Comment: I'm on Mac.  I'm going to try "npm install n" and then "n latest"

Comment: Hmm. You could just go to http://nodejs.org and re-install from their .dmg package for Mac OS X...